# Backbone.js + Rails 3.1: How to create CMS within Admin namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, backbone.js

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a while now, and have been researching on the web with little success. I can't be the only one, right?

How do you create a CMS within a namespace using Backbone?

In rails it is relatively simple, but adding backbone into the equation seems tricky.

Here's my basic application so far:

Relative Gems

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc4'  
gem 'devise'  
gem 'rails-backbone', '0.5.0'
```

Basic App Structure

```
/app
  /assets
    /javascripts
      /backbone
        /controllers
          - posts_controller.coffee
        /models
          - post.coffee
        /templates
          /posts
            - edit.jst.ejs
            - index.jst.ejs
            - new.jst.ejs
            - post.jst.ejs
            - show.jst.ejs
        /views
          /posts
            - edit_view.coffee
            - index_view.coffee
            - new_view.coffee
            - post_view.coffee
            - show_view.coffee
  /controllers
    /admin
      - admin_controller.rb
      - posts_controller.rb
    - application_controller.rb
    - posts_controller.rb
  /models
    - post.rb
  /views
    /admin
      /posts
        - index.html.haml
    /posts
      - index.html.haml
```

Routes.rb

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :posts
    root :to => "posts#index"
  end

resources :posts
root :to => "posts#index"
```

Do you have to create another "admin" directory within the backbone views and controllers like the rails structure? Like rails, do they reference the same 'un-namespaced' backbone post model?

How would you then route your backbone structure to pull the correct views while limiting access to edit, new, delete duties - and how would they be referenced?

For example, the normal backbone controller class is defined like...
`class Appname.Controllers.PostsController extends Backbone.Controller`

Would this be the proper way to define the namespaced controller?
`class Appname.Controllers.Admin.PostsController extends Backbone.Controller`

There are a lot of questions here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at the latest version of backbone.  Controller has been renamed to Router.  That may help some.